# Signed sum of sin and cos

Tags: trigonometry, summation, closed-form

In the study of graphical representations of the Ising model I have encountered the following sum for natural numbers $a,b$ such that $b \leq a$

$$
\sum_{\theta \in \{ \frac{ 2 \pi k}{q}, k = 0, \dots , q-1 \}} (-\sin(\theta))^{a-b} \cos(\theta)^b. 
$$

Does this expression have a closed formula?

Comment: FWIW, you can factor out a $(-1)^{a-b}$ and move it outside the summation.